# Proving that $\tau = \{N,\varnothing\}\cup \{S_n:n\in\mathbf{N}\}$ is a topology on $\mathbf{N}$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, infinity

I am required to show that $\tau = \{N,\varnothing\}\cup \{S_n:n\in\mathbf{N}\}$ where $S_n := \{1,\dots,n\},\forall n\in\mathbf{N}$ is a topology on $\mathbf{N}$, the part where i am experiencing some dfficulty is in proving that the union of a countably infinite subset of $\{S_n:n\in\mathbf{N}\}$ belongs to $\tau$.

Here is my attempt so far, Is it correct?

Let $\mathcal{A} =\{S_{\lambda_1},S_{\lambda_2},S_{\lambda_3},\dots\}$ be an infinite subset of $\{S_n:n\in\mathbf{N}\}$, where we assume without loss of generality that $\lambda_j<\lambda_k$ whenever $j<k$. We demonstrate that 
$$\bigcup_{r=1}^{\infty}S_{\lambda_r} = \mathbf{N}$$

*Proof.* Prior to addressing the main claim, we first prove that result that $\lambda_{n}\ge n,\forall n\in\mathbf{N}$, by recourse to Mathematical Induction. The base case is trivial, so we assume that $\lambda_k\ge k$ for some arbitrary $k\in\mathbf{N}$, thus $\lambda_k+1\ge k+1$, but $\lambda_{k+1}>\lambda_k$, implying $\lambda_{k+1}\ge \lambda_k+1$, so $\lambda_{k+1}\ge k+1$, completing the induction. Now let $n\in\mathbf{N}$, obviously $n\in S_n$, but since $n\leq\lambda_n$, it follows that $S_n\subseteq S_{\lambda_n}$, consequently $n\in S_{\lambda_n}$ and thus $\mathbf{N}\subseteq\bigcup_{r=1}^{\infty}S_{\lambda_r}$, the converse of which is trivial.

$\blacksquare$

---

Comment: Your induction hypothesis should be $\lambda_k \geq k$, not $\lambda_k > k$.  Otherwise the base case is wrong.  Also, the fact that $n\in \lambda_n$ doesn't immediately imply that $n\in \bigcup S_{\lambda_r}$ since $\lambda_r$ is not neccesarily equal to $n$ for any $r$.  But you can save it easily since $S_n\subseteq S_m$ whenever $n\leq m$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, Thanks again for pointing out the second error too.

Comment: One last comment:  When you write "countably infinite subset of $\{S_n:n\in \mathbf{N}\}$ belongs to $\tau$", the "countably" is a bit distracting.  In order to be a topology, $\tau$ must be closed under arbitrary infinite unions, not just countable ones.  That said, because $\tau$ is itself countable, it is ok in this case to just look at counable unions.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, Thanks again your counsel is higly appreciated.

Comment: Will it not be the case that if we take arbitrary union, without considering whether it is countable or not, we still get a proof. Because, in this arbitrary union, every set is of the form $\left\lbrace 1, 2, \cdots, n \right\rbrace$. Now, if we collect all such $n$'s, and get an upper bound, the union would be the set $\left\lbrace 1, 2, \cdots, m \right\rbrace$ where $m$ is the least upper bound of our collected $n$'s. And if we do not get an upper bound, then the union is $\mathbb{N}$ which is still in the set $\tau$. Therefore, $\tau$ is a topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is OK, but the proof should be set up for arbitary unions, and then the union is not always $\mathbb{N}$, though it often is:

Let $O_i$, $ i \in I$ be an arbitary union of open sets. We can WLOG omit any $O_i = \emptyset$, because they do not contribute to the union, and if any $O_i = \mathbb{N}$, so is the union and we are done. So all $O_i$ are then of the form $O_i = \{1, \ldots, n(i)\}$ for some $n(i) \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now there are two cases when considering the set $N = \{n(i): i \in I\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

a) $N$ is bounded above and thus $\max N$ exists. If this is the case, $\bigcup_i O_i = \{1,\ldots, \max N\}$, as all $O_i$ are subsets of that set (as $n(i) \le \max N$) and at least one $O_i$ actually equal to that right hand set.

b) $N$ is not bounded above and then $\bigcup_i O_i = \mathbb{N}$: let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then for some $i$, $n(i) > n$ by unboundedness, and then $n \in O_i = \{1,\ldots, n(i) \} \subseteq \bigcup_i O_i$.

So the topology is closed under **all** unions, as we needed to show.